# undefined reference when using c++11 qmake flags

Tags: c++11, qmake, undefined-reference

I have a Qt C++ application that includes a third-party library (along with its *.h* header file). However, when I set `QMAKE_CCFLAGS += -std=c++11` and `CONFIG += c++11`, I get undefined reference for function calls to this third-party library.

It compiles without c++11 flags.

Is there a way to resolve this?

This is *qmake* specific when using `c++11` flags in the qmake configuration. The DLL file is linked with qmake LIBS and **is compiling without** the c++11 qmake configuration flag.

Once I set:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
CONFIG += c++11
```

compiling gives me unresolved symbol errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I believe it is not because this is happening when I link third party DLL with header files with C api functions (wrapped in extern C) using qmake, mingw, qt framework **only** with c++11 flags ON. Without them works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285706/trouble-using-wxwidgets-3-0-2-library-under-mingw-64) answer and it resulted in a successful compilation.

It works when I add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 4.9.1 32bit