# Error "is_enum not declared in this scope" when trying to compile my wxWidgets program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks, wxwidgets

The G++ compiler shows the following errors when I try to compile:

```
C:\wx\include\wx\strvararg.h|350|error: 'is_enum' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type|
C:\wx\include\wx\strvararg.h|354|error: 'is_enum' was not declared in this scope|
C:\wx\include\wx\strvararg.h|354|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
```

I am using Code::Blocks for this, with a non-monolithic DLL build of wxWidgets.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds like you don't have C++11 enabled.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compilation errors are printed.

Comment: how would I enable c++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian already indicated, you should enable C++11. There are two ways of doing this as you can see [What are the differences between -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613126/what-are-the-differences-between-std-c11-and-std-gnu11).

As I remember, when compiling the whole wxWidgets library, I used -std=gnu++11 and had no problems.

Comment: How would I add -std=gnu++11 to the command for compiling wxwidgets with mingw?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285706/trouble-using-wxwidgets-3-0-2-library-under-mingw-64

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to macroland comment:

You should consider upgrading to gcc version 5.2+. This version(s) does have a full set of c++11 features, whereas previous versions have them partially.